# How to change Listbox item color from selected Item(object)?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have the following code and I hope to accomplish to change Color from Listbox item associated to that object in items:

```
        foreach (var item in lbMine.Items)
        {
            MyClass current = (MyClass)item;
            if (current.ID == someParamSentID)
            {
                //How to change listbox color based on 'item'?
            }
        }
```

I'm looking for a solution that I don't have to change the xaml.

thanks

Comment: Get a ListBoxItem by `(ListBoxItem)lbMine.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(current)`.

Comment: thanks, it worked great, make it as an answer so I can mark as answered. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get the ListBoxItem that contains the current item by calling the [`ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
if (current.ID == someParamSentID)
{
    var lbItem = (ListBoxItem)lbMine.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(current);
    ...
}
```